# how to automatically zoom mapView to show overlay

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, mkpolygon

I am able to draw the polygon on mapView however I need to locate the polygon and zoom it manually. Is there a way to do this process automatically like adjust the polygon in centre? I have browsed the internet and read few related articles, most of them are based on polylines and points. Any kind of help will be appreciated, as I am finding for the solution for a while. Thanks in advance.

Using the following methods to draw the polygon on mapView : -

```
func drawFence(coordinates: UnsafePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, count: Int) {
        let makePoly = MKPolygon(coordinates: coordinates, count: count)
        mapview.addOverlay(makePoly)
    }

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    guard let polyOverlay = overlay as? MKPolygon else { return MKOverlayRenderer() }
    let polyRender = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: polyOverlay)
    polyRender.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882, green: 0.09803921569, blue: 0.2588235294, alpha: 0.6)
    polyRender.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882, green: 0.09803921569, blue: 0.2588235294, alpha: 1)
    polyRender.lineWidth = 2
    return polyRender
}
```

Comment: try this will zoom/pan to fit all overlays with a little buffer :
if let first = mapView.overlays.first {
    let rect = mapView.overlays.reduce(first.boundingMapRect, combine: {MKMapRectUnion($0, $1.boundingMapRect)})
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 50.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 50.0), animated: true)
}

Comment: @DhavalRaval i have tried this code before, and there is no property called "MKMapRectUnion"

Comment: @Rob thanks, the title suggested by you makes sense, I have changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you’re trying to zoom into a particular overlay, you can:

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50)

func zoom(for overlay: MKOverlay) {
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(overlay.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: insets, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

---

If you want to zoom the map to show all the overlays, you can do:

```
func zoomForAllOverlays() {
    guard let initial = mapView.overlays.first?.boundingMapRect else { return }

    let mapRect = mapView.overlays
        .dropFirst()
        .reduce(initial) { $0.union($1.boundingMapRect) }

    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, edgePadding: insets, animated: true)
}
```

For example, having added two overlays (over NYC and Stamford), I called that routine, and it resulted in:

[image: mapview w two overlays]

---

By the way, I know the question was about `Polygon` overlays, but the technique works regardless of the overlay type. It was just simpler to create `Circle` overlays for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I have made the necessary code changes as mentioned, and it worked like a charm for both the overlays.

Comment: I am calling zoomForAllOverlays() in - (void)mapViewWillStartRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView  and it works well.